# Hole community (HU)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Try make sense of the image below.

---

[image]

---

Answer: **2 3 1 3 1 2**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image represents:

> a hand of heads-up Texas Hold'em.  The five community cards at the top are the 10 of hearts, 7 of hearts, 3 of clubs, 10 of clubs, and 6 of hearts.  The player to the left has the two hole cards 10 of spades and 10 of diamonds, giving her four of a kind (tens).  In order for the player on the right to have a winning hand, they'd need two hole cards that would produce a better hand than four of a kind, which is possible if he has the 8 and 9 of hearts, making a straight flush.
>
> The 8 and 9 of hearts at the bottom correspond to the boxes with 'lho' and 'emd' in them.  The answer 2 3 1 3 1 2 refers to the letters in those positions within the two strings: H O L D E M, which is the name of the game being played.

Comment: Grr! rot13(V jnf ybbxvat sbe guvatf gb qb jvgu RZQGNJRVS be RZQGNJYUB (n fgenvtug syhfu vf _svir_ pneqf, nsgre nyy) naq jnf uhat hc ba gur vqrn gung 2,3,1,3,1,2 jrer tbvat gb or jbeq yratguf fbzrubj. (Gbgny jbhyq or evtug vs jr vapyhqrq nyy sbhe pneqf gung _pbhyq_ or hfrq gb znxr n fgenvtug syhfu.) Q'bu. :-))